# Como realizar unit testing a controllers que tienen type hinting en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Desde ayer que me estuve comiendo la cabeza pero no le pude dar una solucion a este problema, resulta que estoy tratando de hacer un test a un controller proveniente de una ruta get que devuelve el resultado del  registro de una base de datos, pero al hacer el test no me devuelve nada (me arroja null) , es decir, no me esta retornando los resultados de la base de datos.

Mostrando el codigo es mas facil de entender:

Ruta:

```
Route::get("/compania/{cp}","controllerCompania@saber_nombre_compania")->name("ver.compania");
```

Controller:

```
public function saber_nombre_compania(compania $cp){
    dd($cp->nombre) //En el proyecto real... aca me aparece el nombre 
    de la compañia
 }
```

El test de phpunit:

```
public function test_nombre(){

   $prueba= $this->get(route("ver.compania",["cp"->"mi-compania"]))
  }
```

En el proyecto real lo tengo asi el acceso al controller (con use de blade) y si sirve:

```
 {{-- $cp->name lo saco de otro controller pero el resultado es "mi- 
  compania" --}}


 <a href="{{route("ver.compania",["cp"=>{{$cp->name}}])}}">acceder</a>
```

Aca les muestro una imagen de lo que me muestra el terminal utilizando el comando de phpunit:

[image: Error de mensaje]

Que intente hasta ahora?

Si le quito el type hint al controllador (companies), si me toma el valor que le coloco al route en la prueba, pero obviamente pierdo las funcionalidades de la clase compañia.

Porque uso el type hint?

Porque de esta manera las url las hago amigables, en vez de ser:

```
mipagina.com/empresa/1
```

es

```
mipagina.com/empresa/mi-empresa
```

Y esto lo hago por medio de los slugs.

En la vida real, si sirve, pero haciendo test no.

Alguien sabe que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que en tus pruebas estés usando una base de datos distinta a la que usas normalmente (una base de datos en memoria? sqlite? otra mysql?, en fin) prueba creando un objeto en el mismo método y luego trata de acceder mediante la ruta:

```
public function test_nombre()
{
    /** Crea una compañía usando un factory o del modo que quieras */
    $company = factory(Company::class)->create(['name' => 'coca-cola'])

    /** Ahora sí realiza tus aserciones */
    $prueba = $this->get(route('ver.compania', ['cp' => 'coca-cola']));
    // ...
}
```

---

PD: Ahí no parece que estuvieras probando nada, pero imagino que simplificaste el código para simplificar la pregunta.